# Linking against GTest fails

Tags: cmake, googletest

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# adding library
set(ST_SRC simple_tree.cpp)
add_library(st ${ST_SRC})
target_include_directories(st PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/data_structures/simple_tree/)

# adding googletest
set(GOOGLETEST_PATH ~/local/googletest)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ~/local/include/)
set(GTEST_LIBRARY ~/local/lib/)
set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY ~/local/lib/)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

# adding tests
set(TEST_TARGET test_simple_tree)
add_executable(${TEST_TARGET} test_simple_tree.cpp)
target_include_directories(${TEST_TARGET}
                        PUBLIC
                        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/data_structures/simple_tree
                        ${GOOGLETEST_PATH}
                        ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${TEST_TARGET} PUBLIC st)
target_link_libraries(${TEST_TARGET} PUBLIC gtest gtest_main)
```

Basically, I've installed `googletest` into my home directory rather than system-wide.
The `find_package()` command apparently succeeds. However, trying to build `test_simple_tree` fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main
```

Inside this `CMakeLists.txt`, how else can I tell the linker to look elsewhere
for the `gtest`?

EDIT: After reading the docs, I've fixed the `Gtest` issue as described below. However, the following issue cropped up: [CMake imported target includes non-existent path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010477/cmake-imported-target-includes-non-existent-path)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but this CMake file should not need to add include directories for Google Test to the `test_simple_tree` target.  That should be handled automatically by CMake when you declare a dependency using `target_link_libraries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `find_package()` was successful in finding the GTest includes/libraries, it should populate targets for you, per the CMake [`FindGTest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html) documentation:

> This module defines the following `IMPORTED` targets:
>
> `GTest::GTest`:
>      The Google Test `gtest` library, if found; adds Thread::Thread automatically
>
> `GTest::Main`:
>      The Google Test `gtest_main` library, if found

You should use these in your `target_link_libraries()` command instead. Also, CMake will populate `GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS`, but the GTest include directories should be pulled in from the *imported targets* mentioned above.

---

Another important note: I'm not sure if you posted *all* of your CMake code, but I don't see a `project()` call in your code. As a result, the `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` variable may not be what you expect. In general, it is good practice to declare your project with `project()` at the top of your CMake.

Your CMake file with these modifications could look something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(simple_tree_example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# adding library
set(ST_SRC simple_tree.cpp)
add_library(st ${ST_SRC})
target_include_directories(st PUBLIC 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/data_structures/simple_tree/)

# adding googletest
set(GOOGLETEST_PATH ~/local/googletest)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ~/local/include/)
set(GTEST_LIBRARY ~/local/lib/)
set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY ~/local/lib/)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

# adding tests
set(TEST_TARGET test_simple_tree)
add_executable(${TEST_TARGET} test_simple_tree.cpp)
target_include_directories(${TEST_TARGET}
                        PUBLIC
                        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/data_structures/simple_tree
                        ${GOOGLETEST_PATH})
target_link_libraries(${TEST_TARGET} PUBLIC st GTest::GTest GTest::Main)
```

Comment: I agree about the `project()`, but I was building this only as a small module inside a larger one, hence `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` should refer to the "root" directory, and so it does (the IDE shows appropriate autocomplete prompts).

Answer (score 2):

Targets `gtest` and `gtest_main` are created only when GTest is used via `add_subdirectory()` approach.

When use GTest via `find_package()`, one need to use either IMPORTED targets `GTest::GTest` and `GTest::Main`, or variables `GTEST_LIBRARIES` and `GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES` correspondingly. This is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindGTest.html):

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(test_simple_tree PUBLIC GTest::GTest gtest_main)
```

or

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
...
# That case we need to add include directories
target_include_directories(test_simple_tree ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(test_simple_tree PUBLIC ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES})
```