# CMake imported target includes non-existent path

Tags: cmake, googletest

I've followed the steps described in [Linking against GTest fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009607/linking-against-gtest-fails), and get this error.

```
CMake Error in src/impl/data_structures/simple_tree/CMakeLists.txt:
      Imported target "GTest::GTest" includes non-existent path

        "~/local/include/"
```

Further messages include:

```
in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.
```

EDIT: Although it loses "generality", I replaced the `~/` path with
the full path, and then get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /home/myself/local/lib/: File format not recognized
```

The path exists, to be sure.

Comment: Does the path exist? Try removing the `~`, and write out the full path instead.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want all important information to be included into the question post itself. Your code definitely is a reason of such problems, so please, add it into the question post. Linking to the other question could be useful, but it doesn't replace the needs of the code to be in the question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59009607/3987854), you are hinting to `find_package()` where to find GTest with a few `GTEST_*` variables. The library variables should provide the fully qualified name of the *actual library file*, not the *location* of the libraries. When you only provide the path, the `FindGTest.cmake` module uses this path as the actual library when it wraps the imported targets; this is incorrect. Try modifying your CMake to something like this, then re-run CMake from scratch:

```
# adding googletest
set(GOOGLETEST_PATH /home/username/local/googletest)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR /home/username/local/include/)
set(GTEST_LIBRARY /home/username/local/lib/path/to/libgtest.a)
set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY /home/username/local/lib/path/to/libgtest_main.a)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

For what it's worth, you really shouldn't have to set all of the variables before calling `find_package()`. You should only need to set `GTEST_ROOT` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649433/3987854) answer.

Comment: _hinting_ is the keyword here. In fact the designated directories contained both `*.so` and `*.a` libraries. However, after using this method I was getting `make` errors about "% missing in target", or something. So I completely switched to the method of downloading googletest during cmake's configure phase, as described in the relevant `README`, and that worked.